# how to do acircular shift for an array via verilog

Tags: arrays, memory, verilog, fpga, timing

In C language, there is an array x[0], x[1], ..., x[127], for a given number k in [0, 127), we difine left shift operation as y[n] = x[(n+k)%128], for n=0,1,2...,127

Now I am try to implement this in FPGA, as there are so many this type operations, I like to get the result as fast as possile.

I did this as follows,

```
module LEFT_SHIFT(
    input clk,
    input rst,
    input [31:0] data_in[0:127])
    input [6:0]  shift,
    output reg [31:0] data_ou[0:127]
);

integer i;
always @ (posedge clk)
begin
    if (rst)
        for (i=0;i<128;i++)
            data_out[i] <= 32'bb0;
    else
        for (i=0;i<128;i++)
            data_out[(i+shift)%128] = data_in[i];
end

endmodule
```

Is this code fine in terms speed, resource and timing? I looks like a RAM, but RAM does't output all the memory at the same time.

Many thanks,

Jerry

Comment: Do you have to move the data circularly, or is it sufficient to **access** it circularly?

Comment: yes, I need to circularly move the data.

Answer (score 1):

If you replace the Mod operator (%) with a replication of the input data to make the circular shift you could make the task easier for the compiler. I tried this on the synthesis tool from a major ASIC tool vendor and the results were quite different.

```
if (rst)
  for (integer i=0;i<128;i++)
    data_out[i] <= 32'b0;
else begin      
  logic [31:0] tmp [0:255];
  for (integer i=0;i<128;i++) begin
    // replicate input data
    tmp[i]     = data_in[i];
    tmp[i+128] = data_in[i];
  end

  for (integer i=0;i<128;i++)
    data_out[i] <= tmp[128-shift+i];
end
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a huge mux that will consume a lot of logic resources in the FPGA. I've seen things like that crash the tools before. You may want to consider adding more than just one register in there.

As far as speed, resource, and timing goes, it depends on how fast you want it to run and how many free resources you have. It could be fine at low speed on a big FPGA or impossible at higher speeds or small/full FPGA. But there's no need to speculate about resource and timing, just build it and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks Justin.  Yes, it does consume lots of resources in FPGA. I am thinking to reduce the resouce a little at the cost of some additional clock cycles, say 4 cycles for example.Iintuitively, this would need several tempary registers, but I am not very clear how to implement this, any hints?  thanks and regards.

Comment: If your tools can do retiming, add registers before and/or after and let them get pulled in automatically. If not, break it up, e.g. 16x mux -> reg -> 8x mux -> reg.

Comment: Now, I rewrite the code, dividing the shift into three step, first left shift n0 (n0 < 8), then left-shift 8*n1 (n1 < 4), then left-shift 32*n2 (n2 <4), in each step, I take FFs to store the temporary results, then final delay is 3 clock cycles.

Comment: In Synthesis, there is a warning as below.
[Netlist 29-101] Netlist 'top' is not ideal for floorplanning, since the cellview 'top' contains a large number of primitives.  Please consider enabling hierarchy in synthesis if you want to do floorplanning.
Although timing is good at current test as I just instantize one module, I believe there should be some timing issues when resource utilization increases. Do you have any comments?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the floorplaning warning unless you plan to do that. Yes, timing will get harder as the usage increases. But 8x and 4x muxes aren't that big, so I wouldn't optimize it any more until you start failing timing.